# Best way to work with multiple http calls in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have the following scenario. I need to make 3 http calls, the return the result of all 3 requests. The problem is that I haven't found a way to do this synchronously. What is the best way to tackle this in NodeJS?

Comment: Does each request need information from the last? or do you have all the information to make all three requests at the start?

Comment: No they don't need information from each other. I have everything I need to call all 3.

Comment: Use Promise.all() and request library that returns promise for each request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard built in way for javascript es5+ is to use promises, and promise all to wait for when they are finished.

```
let req1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ///http request that resolves/rejects
});

let req2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ///http request that resolves/rejects
});

let req3 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ///http request that resolves/rejects
});

Promise.all([req1, req2, req3]).then(function (values) {
    console.log(values);
});
```

something like.

Answer (score 0):

There are countless modules for this. I personally use `async` a lot and for this purpose you could use `async.eachSeries()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to "promisify" your requests. There are multiple ways, but the library that I like most (and I think is one of the most completed ones) is [Bluebirdjs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) . With bluebird you can promisify complete libraries and of course your own requests.

```
Promise.promisify(
    function(any arguments..., function callback) nodeFunction,
    [Object {
        multiArgs: boolean=false,
        context: any=this
    } options]
) -> function
```

for instance:

```
var getAsync = Promise.promisify(redisClient.get);
getAsync.call(redisClient, 'foo').then(function() {
    //...
});
```

Check some examples here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/working-with-callbacks.html#more-common-examples